# Azure equivalent of securing Function to a particular role

Tags: azure, azure-functions

What's the closest equivalent in Azure to an AWS Lambda, that is only accessible with a given IAM role?

It looks like Azure Functions are fairly wide open by default (like a Lambda + API gateway as a single resource), and I'm wondering how to best replicate the kind of behavior where a function is only available to a service principal or a user already authenticated with Azure.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do to secure Functions. You can enable app service authorization and authentication, deploy them in App Service Environments, and restrict with Function keys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production

Comment: The closest thing I've found is app service authentication, but then I still have to check claims in my own code.  I was hoping there was something that would externalize checking that the user is in a specific role.